# How to better handle having the same classes in two JARs

Tags: java, jar

I wrote two jars. Each one of them is responsible for sending different http/https request.

Each one of them uses, naturally, certain same classes. Like the ones that builds the requests or send them. The process might be a bit different, but still the general structure and classes names are the same.

Building different jars per request is a requirement from my managers! So using 1 jar for all my http requests is not acceptable.

Now, in my client program I need to send a request one time for JarA and one time from JarB. But compilation fails because, naturally, I am using very similar namings for the classes and methods.

For example, I have a UserData class in both jars. So when I try to use it in my client program, the compiler yells: "reference to SystemData is ambiguous".

I can start improvising specific classes names for each jar, but it is ugly...

How would you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Put the common classes in a third jar and add it to the classpath when running either of the two others?!

Comment: ... even if you use similar naming for the classes, you should definitely use different package within your two jars. Change of package name is easy with any half-decent java ide.

Comment: eis, package names are different, Thanks

Comment: @eis I think your idea is not helpful. He is talking about the SAME classes. Having them twice in different packages just opens a can of worms with problems.

Comment: @EddyG no, he is not. "Like the ones that builds the request... the process might be a bit different, but still the general structure and class names are the same". Based on description by OP, it does not seem that the classes is identical. They have same general structure and class name. That's a different thing.

Comment: @dushkin if package names are different, you can just use fully qualified name for the class without any issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classes are identical, pull them out into a third JAR and then have the client program reference the common JAR plus JarA or JarB.

If the classes are similar but not identical, then put them into different packages. You can have classes with the same names if they're in different packages.

Answer (score 1):

Put common classes in a third jar and either bundle it in the two http jars or add it to the classpath at runtime (which is the best choice will depend on how you're deploying, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to decide which kind of architecture you are working with.
If managers asking you to have different jar's for sake of modularization - sure it's worth to make common jar which will contain all common classes.

I suppose you should have your project built with Maven, Gradle or another build system which will help you managing dependencies.

Another issue could be if you are supposed to do 'Microservices' architecture. Then code duplication is inevitable.

To overcome same class names when you have duplication - I would recommend to have for every module different package names then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a build system like **maven** where one can have library dependencies, to a common third jar. It maintains a repository of versioned jars.

Comment: I don't see how just moving to a build system like maven changes the problem in any way. Surely you can have dependencies in a third jar equally well even without maven?

Comment: @eis yes (for instance ant+ivy), but maven enforces a versioning like: `a-1.5.jar, b-1.6.jar, common-1.6,jar, a-2,0.jar common-2.0.jar` being kept parallel in the maven library repository. As this question asks for a "best practice," a tool that on builds can inform about having newer jars available etcetera, makes sense. Overkill if maven would not be easy and professional.

Answer (score 0):

**One solution is that -** if you see a same class with same package in two different jars and both jars are required in your project,

> Solution

- `you can download the source code of that duplicate class and creat  keep the same in your project with package structure. So this way JVM loads your project classes first and give first preference to invoke your project class rather then other jar's class`